# Errors trying instantiate JDatePicker

Tags: java, date

Using examples from the internet, I'm trying to make a new JDatePicker, but I'm getting an error.

My method:

```
public JDatePicker drawDateChooser(){

 UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();

 JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model);  

 JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel);

    return datePicker;
}
```

The errors are saying that the datePanel needs a "DateModel, Properties" not a "UtilDateModel", as well as the datePicker needs a "JDatePanelImpl, AbstractFormatter", not just the former. Thanks!

Comment: This is the general example online and they say its fine the way it is. I'm not sure what must've changed except possibly for the fact that the code was updated.

Comment: Hint: it seems that you really are lacking the absolute basics of Java programming. If so: please do not start with UI programming. Go for smaller examples that do not in include UI stuff. There is no point in learning how to juggle ... whilst reading the unicycle for the first time. Learn about the basics, then, when you mastered those ... go forward to the more advanced stuff.

Comment: @Jägermeister I don't mean to come off as pretentious or anything, this is just one of the first times I've ever dealt w/ GUI's. ik I have to declare a new AbstractFormatter class for the Date return, its mostly the "Properties" part that confuses me. Thank you though for your concern, every error is a battle in its own!